# Getting average of top 1/3 values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1-D array with over 100 values that changes depending on the case. I need to find a way to easily determine the highest one-third of the values and then calculate their average. For example, if my array was [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] the highest 1/3 of the values would be [7,8,9] and then the average would be 8. I just have too many values and the amount of values change every time to do this manually. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For an array that tiny, any reason you can't just sort it?

Comment: By "top 1/3", do you mean the top floor(N/3) values, or all values above 66th percentile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the most beatiful solution but solves your problem fast.

In this solution i will get the smaller integer if `len(vect)/3` is not a integer.  I do this because if the lenght of your vector is not divisible by 3 you will have a non integer number for 1/3.
If you want to get the next integer. Ex. len(vect)/3 = 5.6 you want 6. then change math.floor function and use math.ceil.

```
import math
import numpy as np

vect =  [1,7,3,4,9,6,2,8,5]

np.mean(np.sort(vect)[len(vect)-math.floor(len(vect)/3):])

#Return:
#8 --- the mean of [7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
q=np.quantile(arr, 2/3)
arr[arr>q].mean()
```

It is faster than `sort`. Because it doesn't really need to sort all values.
Although it is the same order of magnitude.

For example, for an array size 1000000, the sort based solution takes 120 ms on my PC, while this solution takes 36 ms.

But I must admit, for 100 values, there is no need for optimization, and cost is just in overhead probably.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) is probably the way to go.

In numpy you can use [`np.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) to implement it.

```py
k = int(np.ceil(len(arr) * 2 / 3))
mean = np.partition(arr, k)[k:].mean()
```

On my computer this is slightly faster than the naive `np.sort(arr)[k:].mean()` method when `len(arr)` is 100.

However, when `len(arr)` is 1_000_000 then this is significantly faster than either `np.quantile` approach proposed by @chrslg (which likely uses quickselect as well) or the naive sort approach.

#### Benchmarking

```
len(arr) == 100 (average of 10_000 trials)
sort: 0.00131 ms
quantile: 0.00923 ms
partition: 0.00117 ms

len(arr) == 1_000_000 (average of 100 trials)
sort: 5.794 ms
quantile: 1.358 ms
partition: 0.792 ms
```

Comment: Nice. That is faster than quantile indeed. I guess this is because with `quantile` I do the partition twice. Because, normally, you don't compute a quantile to compute a partition. But, on the contrary, you compute a partititon to compute a quantile (it is a sort of aborted quicksort, that stops when it get a partition of k top numbers). `np.partition(arr, k)[k:].min()` computes exactly as fast as `np.quantile(arr, 2/3)`. Indicating that this is how `quantile` works. So, quantile perform a partition internally to compute quantile. And then I use the result the partition a 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to sort this list so the top three values are actually the highest values.

The command used to sort lists in python is `<list_object>.sort()`

Since I don't have your values I'm gonna generate a list with random values:

```
from random import randint
values = [random.randint(1,100) for value in range(100)]
values.sort()
```

This will result in a crescent ordered list.

Now we get the 1/3 equivalent value:

```
third = round(len(values)/3)
```

The result is le **len**gth of the list divided by three and rounded up.

Now we sum the last 1/3 values of that list:

```
one_third = sum(values[-third:])/len(values[-third:])
```

This is what you need, in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution similar to the previous one.

```
from statistics import mean
from math import floor

vect = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

cut = floor(len(vect)/3)

print(max(vect[:cut], vect[cut:2*cut], vect[2*cut:], key=lambda x:mean(x)))
```

Instead of printing you can return the list with the highest 1/3 values. I used an additional variable cut for the clarity and key in the max function to choose the biggest one based on the mean of the cut fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I took the source array (a *Numpy* array) as:

```
arr =  np.array([1, 7, 3, 4, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1])
```

My first assumption is that it is enough to round **down** the
size of the source array, so the proper formula can be:

```
arr.size // 3
```

The second assumption is that you don't need to perform "full" sort.
It is enough to call *np.partition*, where:

- The first argument is the source array.
- The second argument is the "threshold": Initial *n* elements are
  "smaller" and the rest are "bigger".

So the proper threshold, leaving 2/3 of smaller elements should be:

```
n = arr.size - arr.size // 3
```

getting *7*.

And the partitioning should be called as:

```
np.partition(arr, n)
```

To take the "bigger" elemenst (last 1/3), we can use indexing as:

```
[n:]
```

so the code to get the "bigger" part is:

```
np.partition(arr, n)[n:]
```

getting *array([7, 8, 9])*.

And to get the mean, we can call *np.mean*, so the whole code is:

```
result = np.mean(np.partition(arr, n)[n:])
```